# How to modify the content of a string using Regular Expression (Just like String.Replace)

Tags: python, regex

I want to replace the content of a string using regex in python.

I have tried the following code:

```
regex=r"(?:ab*)\w+"
text ="absd 2013 abpq ab 123absd"
pattern=re.compile(regex)
print pattern.sub("dummy",text)
```

I got the output like this:

```
dummy 2013 dummy dummy 123dummy
```

But my actual text is still same.

Can I modify the text itself with a regex?

Comment: Re-assign the text variable to the copy with the changes...i.e text=newvalue

Comment: Pro-tip: when in doubt, check the manual. You should find a working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, Strings are immutable. So, you cannot change them. What you can do is, replace the old reference to string object with the new string object, like this

```
text = pattern.sub("dummy", text)
```

Also, if you are trying to replace all the strings which start with `ab`, then you might want to use this RegEx,

```
regex = r"ab.*?\b"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the result back into the text as follows:

```
text = pattern.sub("dummy",text)
```

`sub`:

> Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost non-overlapping
>   occurrences of pattern in string by the replacement repl

This "returned string" is not actually the original replaced string. It is a ***new*** string that contains the replaced string. Therefore, you need to assign it back to the original string

Now you will the expected modified string:

```
print test
dummy 2013 dummy dummy 123dummy
```